# PHP OOP call method variable from another method

Tags: php, function, oop, methods

I'm newbie at PHP OOP please patient to teach me.

With the code below, the page will call "index" method to be shown.
And the "index" method wants to call from another method (getView).

How to correct the code method of "index".

```
class Report {

    public function index(){
        $over = $this->overview;
        return $over;
    }

    public function getView()
    {
        $overview = 'I want this show up at index';
        return $overview;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry i didn´t understand your question. Can you explain exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: $something = $this->index();

Comment: $overveiw is local to getView() method, you make it public/private variable and access, or call $this->getView() to access the text inside you index() method

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `$overview` is a local variable of the method "getView", so the index method can't see it.
Only getView knows it.

Second, you try to access `$this->overview;`, to do that, $overview must be attribute of the class Report, so your code should start with :

```
class Report {

    private $overview;

    public function index(){
        // (your code...)
    }
```

Third, if you want getView and index to use the same value of $overview, you have to use the attribute in getView too :

```
public function getView()
{
    $this->overview = 'I want this show up at index';
    return $this->overview;
}
```

Finally, for index to see the value set by getView, you have to be sure that getView is called before index. Otherwise, you have to call it manually :

```
class Report {

    private $overview;

    public function index(){
        $this->getView();
        $over = $this->overview;
        // or $over=$this->getView();
        return $over;
    }

    public function getView()
    {
        $this->overview = 'I want this show up at index';
        return $this->overview;
    }
```